# Filtering numpy character array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, biopython

I have a numpy array of letters and '-' - it may have tens of thousands rows and thousands of columns. I would like to move all the '-' to the right (without changing the order of the other letters), and then truncate the array so that no column contains all '-'. I am looking for a fast solution, using perhaps some ingenious use of the built-in numpy routines.

**Background:**
Every row in the array is actually a genetic sequence, where '-' are inserted somewhat randomly for reasons which are not important here. Instead of dealing with an array I could actually save all the sequences as strings, pad them on the right with '-' to match the maximum non-trivial sequence length, and transform into an array. This however turns out rather slow, which is why I am looking for a clever way to do it starting with an array of letters, which is easily obtained
as `np.array(aln)`, where `aln` is sequence biopython alignment object.

**Update**
Here is an example, that hopefully clarifies the question. If I start with array

```
np.array([['-', 'A', 'C', '-', 'T'], ['A', 'G', '-', 'T', 'T']])
```

I want it to be transformed to

```
np.array([['A', 'C', 'T', '-', '-'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T', '-']])
```

and ultimately to

```
np.array([['A', 'C', 'T', '-'], ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T']])
```

Comment: To me it is not clear, what you mean exactly with "I would like to filter all the '-' to the right". Could you maybe append an example array to your question together with the expected result?

Comment: I would like to move all the '-' to the right. @LydiavanDyke

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['-', 'A', 'C', '-', 'T'], ['A', 'G', '-', 'T', 'T']])
new_data = np.tile('-', data.shape)

longest_line = 0
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    not_dash = line != '-'
    n_characters = sum(not_dash)
    new_data[i, :n_characters] = line[not_dash]
    longest_line = n_characters if n_characters > longest_line else longest_line

new_data = new_data[:, :longest_line]
```

Outputs

```
>>> new_data
array([['A', 'C', 'T', '-'],
       ['A', 'G', 'T', 'T']], dtype='<U1')
```